# Loop is not being called but indentation is correct

Tags: python-2.7, loops, arcgis

I have this function I have built and it seems like I am missing something very minor here. This loop will not call for some reason. Indentation looks good and I am not getting any errors in my output, but the data is not being updated which you can see by the debug print statement I made not showing in the terminal.

Below is the function I am speaking of:

```
def updatefield(layer, prev_data):
print("DEUBG:: UPDATE FIELD")
fname, ftype, fdict = field_attr(prev_data)[0], field_attr(prev_data)[1], field_attr(prev_data)[2]

arcpy.AddField_management(
    in_table=layer, 
    field_name=fname, 
    field_type=ftype, 
    field_is_nullable="NULLABLE"
    )

# Use UpdateCursor to expedite the copy of the data to the new field.
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(layer, [prev_data, fname, "OID@"]) as uc:
    print("DEUBG:: UPDATE CURSOR: {}".format(layer))
    for record in uc:
        print("\tDEBUG:: record: {}".format(record)) # THIS NEVER GETS CALLED 
        if record[0] in fdict.keys():
            record[1] = fdict[record[0]]
        else:
            if layer == fms_conduit:
                record[1] = None
            # Can't recall if you can have empty keys...These also pretty much only apply to fiber.
            elif prev_data == "CATEGORY" and record[0] == "":
                record[1] = "OTH"
            elif prev_data == "CABLECAPACITY" and (record[0] in ('', ' ', None)):
                record[1] = 0
            elif prev_data == "CABLECAPACITY":
                record[1] = int(record[0])
            else:
                record[1] = ""
        print("\nDEBUG:: OID: {}\tPrevField: {}\t NewFieldName: {}\tNewFieldValue: {}".format(
            record[2], prev_data, fname, record[1])
        )
        uc.updateRow(record)
```

And here is the output:

[image]

The final few debug print statements are from another function  but I should be getting that record printed. Again, probably something silly but I can't seem to get it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If `"\tDEBUG:: record: {}... "` isn't being printed, `uc` is empty. Why that is though would require some debugging.

Comment: Well, I was trying to figure out why the conversion of the data wasn't happening. But you actually solved my issue right there. UC is empty because a feature class delivered to me was truncated lol. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jason I don't want to sound rude or whatever but even before reading the comments etc, the root cause was already as obvious as an elephant in the room, really - when a for loop on an iterable is skipped, it's because the iterable is empty, quite simply.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the data that was delivered to me was truncated at some point. The update cursor was empty and therefore nothing was being translated.